# PL/SQL SUM Difference Example

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to implement this SQL code in PL/SQL

SQL Code:

```
select  SUM(SUM(distinct inv_total) - SUM(distinct credit_total) ) as TOTAL from invoice
where cus_id =95 
group by inv_total, credit_total
```

PL/SQL Code:

```
Declare 

total invoice.inv_total%TYPE;
cust_id NUMBER := 95;
BEGIN

select  SUM(SUM(distinct inv_total) - SUM(distinct credit_total) ) 
INTO total from invoice
where cus_id= cust_id;
dbms_output.put_line('Total is ' || total);

END;

ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY 
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Any tips how to use GROUP BY with PL/SQL?
Thank you

Comment: Well, maybe it would help if you told us what the problem is?

Comment: I edited the post, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have several problems:

1. I find it highly unlikely that you actually want `distinct` inv_total or credit_total. If two invoices have the same total, you only want to count one of them?
2. Without the distinct, the `sum` can be written 'SUM(inv_total - credit_total)'. This is much more straightforward and will not require a `group by` clause.
3. Your original query groups by inv_total and credit_total. This also doesn't seem right, as you're unlikely want to group multiple rows based on totals like this.
4. If you really wanted the `distinct` and the `group by`, then you'd have to include the `group by` in the PL/SQL block, just as it is in your original SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
DECLARE
total invoice.inv_total%TYPE;
cust_id NUMBER := 95;
BEGIN
select  SUM( inv_total - credit_total) 
INTO total from invoice
where cus_id= cust_id;
dbms_output.put_line('Total is ' || total);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code as;

```
Declare 

total invoice.inv_total%TYPE;
cust_id NUMBER := 95;
BEGIN

select  SUM(
             (select distinct i1.inv_total
                from invoice i1
               where i1.cus_id = I.cus_id ) 
            )  
        - 
        SUM(
             (select distinct i2.credit_total 
                from invoice i2
               where i2.cus_id = I.cus_id ) 
            ) 
INTO total 
from invoice i
where i.cus_id= cust_id;
dbms_output.put_line('Total is ' || total);

END;
```

you can also write the code as

```
Declare 

total invoice.inv_total%TYPE;
cust_id NUMBER := 95;
BEGIN

select  SUM(inv_total - credit_total)
INTO total 
from         (select distinct i1.inv_total, i1.credit_total
                from invoice i1
               where i.cus_id = cust_id ) 
             ); 
dbms_output.put_line('Total is ' || total);

END;
```

choose which suites your requirements

Answer (score -1):

### If were me

select  cus_id, SUM(SUM(inv_total) - SUM(credit_total) ) 
INTO cus_id, total 
from invoice
where cus_id= cust_id
group by cus_id;